# Fechar o entityManager após operações? Como gerenciar?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, arquitetura-de-software

Estive fazendo alguns cursos e todo o material que li até o momento exemplifica o uso do JPA/Hibernate em pequenos exemplos, entretanto, quando estamos desenvolvendo algo mais concreto como um projeto, surgem certas dúvidas.

Por exemplo, antes de toda operação com o banco é preciso iniciar a operação do EntityManager e fazer o commit após a execução da operação.

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(Estado);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

**1º Dúvida : É preciso fechar o EntityManager em algum momento?**
No caso, eu inicei uma transação antes de realizar minhas operações:
"entityManager.getTransaction().begin()". Deveria eu encerrar essa transação de alguma forma? como? através do entityManager.close() ?

**2º Dúvida : Cada método do DAO deve iniciar e commitar a transacao ?**

```
public void inserir(Cidade cidade){
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(cidade);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}

public void remover(Cidade cidade){
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.remove(cidade);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

**3º Dúvida (ACOPLAMENTO) : Como passar o EntityManager de forma mais eficiente a camada DAO?**

Os exemplos aos quais tive acesso funcionavam com uma camada DAO que fazia as operações de base de dados, entretanto, essas DAO's recebiam uma instancia do EntityManager via construtor.

Algo como :

```
public class CidadeDAO implements DAOInterface<Cidade>{
   private EntityManager em;
   public CidadeDAO(EntityManager em){
      this.em = em; 
   }
}
```

Porém isso acaba por me confundir ao trabalhar com esse formato de implementação quando estou desenvolvendo minhas páginas com JSF, isso porque acabo criando um acoplamento que não sei como lidar. Por exemplo, eu sinto a necessidade de recuperar uma instancia do EntityManager em cada **@ManagedBean** para conseguir injetar meus DAO's, e consequentemente me faz declarar um entityManager dentro do ManagedBean e acho que isso é incongruente ao contexto da classe, ja que o certo seria ter todas as ferramentas, objetos e métodos de persistencia nas classes que são reservadas ao fim de realizar transações em bases de dados.

Para ilustrar minha dúvida:

```
@ManagedBean
public class EnderecoBean{
     private EntityManager em;

     public EnderecoBean(){
         this.em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
     }

     public void operacaoExemplo(){
         EstadoDAO dao = new EstadoDAO(em);
         List<Cidade> listaCidades = dao.listar();
     }
}
```

Acho isto estranho, pois se eu tiver multiplos DAO's eu vou precisar de multiplas instancias do EntityManager e isto me parece errado. Alguma solução de como trabalhar a passagem do entityManager para minha camada DAO ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coisas que a gente aprende depois de bater a cabeça:

1) Tentar usar apenas uma variável de jpa durante toda execução.

2) Fechar a conexão no final.

3) Se algo der erro, dar um rollback, fechar a conexão e **não** reaproveitar o objeto do entity manager, gerar outro.

Como fica isso no código?

No DAO - pode usar num genérico que seja extendido por outros para evitar replicação:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory;
EntityManager manager;
```

No início do dao:

```
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceunit");
manager = factory.createEntityManager();    
manager.getTransaction().begin();
```

Em caso de exceção:

```
manager.getTransaction().rollback();
manager.close();
factory.close();
```

Para ser executado no término, depois de executar todas as operações necessárias:

```
manager.getTransaction().commit();
manager.close();
factory.close();
```

---

No Controller ou em quem chamar o dao:

```
private NomeentidadeDAO dao = null;
```

Pode usar um singleton para aproveitar o mesmo dao da entidade:

```
private void getDAO()
{
    if(dao==null)
    {
        dao = new NomeentidadeDAO();
    }
}
```

No final da execução para fechar:

```
if(dao!=null) 
{ 
    dao.end(); 
    // sendo q esse dao.end executa aquele trecho que encerrra a conexão
}
```

Caso dê alguma exceção:

```
    dao.rollbackandclose();  
    // sendo q esse dao.rollbackandclose executa aquele trecho em caso de exceção, visto acima

    dao=null;  // nulifica a variável pra essa não ser reaproveitada (no caso do Hibernate isto é inclusive recomendação)
    // caso precise depois chama o singleton pra gerar outra
```

Answer (score 1):

Partindo do princípio que deve se tratar de uma aplicação web, segue minhas considerações:

1. **Um contexto por request**: A cada request feito à sua aplicação, crie apenas um contexto de repositório. No seu caso, abra a conexão uma vez e inicie a transação. E feche a conexão no fim do request, antes de seu retorno.
2. **Entidades limpas**: Suas entidades de domínio não devem ter dependências nenhuma. Seu comentário foi pertinente, pois em uma lista de `EnderecoBean` vc teria várias instâncias do seu EntityManager, e não é isso que queremos. Entidades devem apenas possuir propriedades, comportamentos, e capacidade de se auto validar. Veja meu github, tem exemplos de [entidades auto validadas](https://github.com/thiagolunardi/auctionhouse/tree/master/src/Auctionata.Domain/Entities), estão em `C#`, mas o princípio é o mesmo.
3. **Aplicação gere transação**: Não é sua camada de DAO que irá gerir a transação. Essa apenas executa o que lhe é solicitado: criar um registro, atualizar, excluir ou selecionar. Mas uma ação, um comando que sua aplicação precisa fazer, muitas vezes, requer várias solicitações ao DAO. Ex: Criar um novo cadastro pode significar inserir dados em várias registros, como pessoa, endereço, login, tudo em uma única transação, que só deverá *comitar* no fim da execução de todo comando. [Veja esse método](https://github.com/thiagolunardi/auctionhouse/blob/master/src/Auctionata.Application/RoomAppService.cs#L37), ele faz várias execuções antes de decidir por `commit` ou `rollback`.

Não vou me aprofundar mais que isso, pois senão se tornará uma resposta muito longa, mas acredito que já possa ajudar a esclarecer algumas ideias.